# Я не нашел и не понял как связать ответы через Checkbutton в Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно по инструкции сделать небольшую программу. Я не нашел и не понял как связать ответы.

[image: 111]
[image: 222]

```
from tkinter import *

def first_label():
    label['text'] = 'ПРАВИЛЬНО'
def second_label():
    label['text'] = 'НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО'
def third_label():
    label['text'] = 'ПРАВИЛЬНО'
def fourth_label():
    label['text'] = 'ПРАВИЛЬНО'

root = Tk()
label1 = Label(root, text="Сколько будет: 1 + 1 =")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

frame = Frame()
frame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W")

first = IntVar()
second = IntVar()
third = IntVar()
fourth = IntVar()

checkbutton_1 = Checkbutton(text="11, для строчного типа данных", command=first_label,
            variable=first).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
checkbutton_2 = Checkbutton(text="5, цена с надбавкой для рыночной экономики", command=second_label,
            variable=second).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="W")
checkbutton_3 = Checkbutton(frame, text="10, для чисел двоичной системы счисления", command=third_label,
            variable=third).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W")
checkbutton_4 = Checkbutton(frame, text="2, для чисел троичной системы счисления и выше", command=fourth_label,
            variable=fourth).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="W")

chb1_label = Label(textvariable=first)
chb2_label = Label(textvariable=second)
chb3_label = Label(textvariable=third)

a_button = Button(text="Проверить", command=third_label)
a_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

label = Label(width=20, height=2)
label.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реакция на изменения состояния каждого конкретного чекбокса не нужна. Делаете обработчик только для нажатия на кнопку, в нем делаете проверку:

1. Если все нужные чекбоксы установлены, а нененужные не установлены, значит правильно
2. Если неправильный чекбокс установлен (один из неправильных чекбоксов, если их несколько), значит неправильно
3. В остальных случаях (т.е. если установлен один или несколько правильных чекбоксов, но не все, и не установлен ни один неправильный) - ответ неполный

Код примерно такой:

```
first = IntVar()
second = IntVar()
third = IntVar()
fourth = IntVar()

Checkbutton(text="11, для строчного типа данных", variable=first).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
Checkbutton(text="5, цена с надбавкой для рыночной экономики", variable=second).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="W")
Checkbutton(frame, text="10, для чисел двоичной системы счисления", variable=third).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W")
Checkbutton(frame, text="2, для чисел троичной системы счисления и выше", variable=fourth).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="W")


def check():
    if first.get() and not second.get() and third.get() and fourth.get():
        label['text'] = 'Верно'
    elif second.get():
        label['text'] = 'Ошибка'
    else:
        label['text'] = 'Ответ не полный'


a_button = Button(text="Проверить", command=check)
```

Совет: не совмещайте запись виджета в переменную и размещение через `grid`, `pack` или `place` - так у вас в переменную запишиется не виджет, а `None` (результат выполнения метода размещения), т.е.:

```
# Неправильно:
checkbutton_1 = Checkbutton(text="11, для строчного типа данных", command=first_label,
            variable=first).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
print(checkbutton_1)  # Выведет None

# Правильно:
checkbutton_1 = Checkbutton(text="11, для строчного типа данных", command=first_label,
            variable=first)
checkbutton_1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
print(checkbutton_1)  # Выведет .!checkbutton
```